# Passing beans between different layer

Tags: java

I need some idea on how to move data between different layers. Usually I plan as follow where each layer has its own POJO.

```
         formPojo                     controllerPojo             servicePojo        
        ===============>             ================>          =============> 
Form/UI                  Controller                     Service                 Dao
        <===============             <===============           <============
         controllerPojo               servicePojo                   dbPojo
```

Major disadvantage of this is even the fields are same and no conversion is required I need to have four different pojo types (*Pojo). So my questions are:

1. What is the proper way to transfer data between layer?
2. I am sure each of these have proper name like Model, DTO, Domain. Can you please explain which one is which according to above diagram.

Thanks

Comment: POJO means Plain Old Java Object, what you mean are DTO as in Data Transfer Object.

Comment: I think it wouldn't be shocking to have a single DTO shared across different layers. Try to think simple. Building a complex "design-for-change" architecture is not always the best solution, I often prefer the "YAGNI" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it ) way to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are using as a Framework. For instance, in Spring MVC you can using backing objects and Model objects for data binding and transfers. Typically these objects are NOT mirror images of each other.

I would recommend reading up on these concepts. For a spring specific implementation see the spring MVC docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html.

I wanted to elaborate on this a bit. Throughout your career as an application developer you will run into these concepts. In terms of creating different objects for different layers we are constantly faced with deciding the best way to separate the tiers, and thus separating the data. It is important to get this right and thankfully there are tools to help.

First however we need to understand the mechanisms provided in order to take advantage of the built in efficiencies provided by the frameworks and containers. Thus understanding Java bean conventions that allows for automatic detection of properties and methods.

There are mappers as well. For instance if I want to take a data object and put some of its contents into a page object. I may use something like Dozer or ModelMapper to help manger the transfer of data between two such objects. This can be simple or complicated depending on your needs.

Of course doing this by hand is the easiest way to learn the ideas behind what these tools provide but one should be aware that these tools exist as they may influence your approach.

Comment: It is important to note that I didn't go into a discussion about the differences or definitions of domain objects, model objects and data transfer objects. This is because they can all be used differently depending on their applicability; there isn't always one answer and there is often overlap. Then other concepts come to mind such as immutability, identity, etc.